# How do I get the play button to trigger the video play action?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, vimeo

On this page I have two divs, div-1 overlapping another div-2 http://55-corinthian-drive.webflow.io/home-video-wip

Div-1 houses the play button (and large image and text), on clicking the play button div-1 toggles off revealing div-2 which houses a Vimeo video. I want the video to start playing once the button is clicked but am unable to get it working. Below is my script for removing div-1 which works fine. I have looked at this idea https://jsfiddle.net/ELHCm/ but wasn't able to get that working, am trying $("#id").vimeo("play"); now.

```
 <!-- triggering div -->
<div class="video-trigger-wrap">
    <h1 class="header">text to remove on click</h1>   
    <div class="video-trigger"></div>  
</div>

<!-- video -->
<div class="div-block-23 position-vid">
    <div id="w-node-df98048f0945" class="video-4 w-video w-embed">       
        <iframe id="g-vid" src="video-address"  frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video-trigger").click(function(){
        $(".video-trigger-wrap").toggle();
        $("#player").vimeo("play");

    });
});
</script> 


Also tried the following, as suggested by Charan below, but has not worked.
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".video-trigger").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             $(".video-trigger-wrap").toggle();
             $("#g-vid").vimeo("play");       
       }); 

  });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'on click' event instead of click event, because you are dynamically appending iframe

```
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $('#video_container').html('<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345?title=1&amp;byline=1&amp;portrait=1&amp;autoplay=true" width="643" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Charan, I added what you suggested to my post above, it hasn't been successful either. Video still does not play on clicking the play button.

Comment: Hey Charan, I've made some progress in that I've got a crude version of it working, hopefully it can develop into what I need. Cheers for the help, will let you know how it works out.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was after http://55-corinthian-drive.webflow.io/home-video-wip  Thanks again!